# Scale features based on field value

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, scale-factor

I have a polygon dataset of 100+ tree canopies - all different shapes and sizes, which I am required to scale by a specific factor to project growth over a number of decades. All canopies have differing scale factors and the shape needs to be retained. Is there a way in ArcGIS to automate this (Python?), potentially by bringing in the scale factors as attributes without having to manually scale each individual canopy?

I need these as an editable output so cannot use a representative symbology for example, as suggested by another post in this forum.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question and provide some examples of what this "scale factor" is and how YOU would use it for say one tree as way of example, because I think everyone else is thinking this if a buffering issue?

Comment: Ok, no this has nothing to do with buffering (although buffering would be an option if I knew the distance to buffer but it is not possible to know that. I would use the Scale tool in Editor toolbar and scale the feature by a a factor of for example, 1.5 for Tree 1, 1.72 for Tree 2, 1.1 for Tree 3 etc. That might be a 10 year development. I would then have to repeat the process for the next decade with different values of scale factors. All of these exist in an Excel sheet so would have been useful to be able to bring this in and do it all in one go.

Comment: However, I have now done this manually for each individual tree and maybe one day someone will come up with a solution to this so I will never have the pain of doing this again.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have explained what it is you are doing, I thought there must be an equivalent geo-processing tool which you could use to automate this processing.  After exploring the Editing tool box I've come to the conclusion there is no equivalent geoprocessing tool, unless I've missed it and it has some other funky name?

That said a very simple search on this forum threw up this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185061/polygon-scaling-using-arcpy) from 7 years ago!  Did you try searching the forum before asking the question?  It achieves exactly what you want with some code.

Comment: Yes I did search the forum. and this post did not come up Now, next time I have to do this I will try the code, we shall see if it lives up to its expectations.