# How to enlarge polygon or a group of polygons by specific amount to each polygon?

Tags: arcpy

I am working on generalization of Geological maps. As an initial step of it I need to enlarge some of the polygons, but different polygon should have different enlargement amount. It is because minimum size constraint, which dictates to remove, enlarge or aggregate all the polygons which have smaller than the fixed amount. For my case, the amount equals to 2500 m2. I decided to remove some of the polygons and enlarge some of them.

I need to enlarge polygons just above the 2500 m2 so that they meet the minimum size constraint, but as different polygon has different area I need to add  different amount to each of them.

I am working with ArcGIS 10.4, also would like to implement python with arcpy library in order to automate it.

Here are some examples of my polygons and part of the table which shows the area of the polygons and how much should be add to each of them.

[Polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAizY.png)

[image: Part of the table]

Comment: Your only option is a rather (computationally) expensive process of scaling features by a factor and using the area difference as feedback into the next attempt, zigging and zagging by a prorated factor until the area value is exact (or exact enough).  If that's what you want to do, you'll need to put some code to attempt it in the question, so we know where to help.

Comment: If scaling polygons by a factor is good enough, try this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169694/is-there-arcpy-tool-for-polygon-resizing-like-scale-tool-of-advanced-editing-too