# How can I scale a feature referring to the area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, scale, arcgis-pro, scale-factor

I'd like to scale features with a scale factor. With the scale tool of the editor toolbar it is possible to define a factor but then every single line of the feature is scaled by this factor. However, I'd like to scale the feature referring to the area and not referring to every line (for example 1.5 times the size it was before). Moreover, I'd like to automise the whole process. Does this only work with a python script?

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro

Comment: To differentiate this from the duplicate perhaps ask about only ArcGIS Pro here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of a geoprocessing tool for this. You could take a look at this question but you need to use some Python: [Is there ArcPy tool for polygon resizing like Scale tool of Advanced Editing toolbar in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169694/is-there-arcpy-tool-for-polygon-resizing-like-scale-tool-of-advanced-editing-too)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this was the only answer I could find, too. But it didn't work so far. Thank you anyway!