# Resizing selection of polygons to percentage of their initial size using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

How do I resize a selection of polygons to a percentage of their initial size (3000 polygons)?

I don't think the Arc "Scaling" tool will be useful as it scales the polygons around a point.  I would like to decrease their size all around their individual centroids.

Comment: Programmatically can be done with arcobjects using `ITransform2D`, which unfortunately doesn't appear to be provided in arcpy.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kirk_Kuykendall states this is something that needs to be resolved with a bit of programming. The ArcObjects way is as he says is using the `ITransform2D` interface but a simple search on this website throws up [Is there ArcPy tool for polygon resizing like Scale tool of Advanced Editing toolbar in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169694) and some python code which you could easily adapt into a script.