# Buffering a polygon keeping the same angle/shape using GeoPandas

Tags: buffer, geopandas

I have an `'area.shp'` (a polygon) file that I would like to buffer with a distance of 1000m. The polygon needs to be read from a folder, and the output needs to be saved with a new name at the same folder.

@BERA's suggestion creates a circle polygon around the polygon using GeoPandas - see script below.

Can GeoPandas expand/buffering keeping the same angle/shape?

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file("C:\GIS\data\testdata\Grid_sample.shp") 
df2 = df.buffer(1000) 
df2.to_file("C:\GIS\data\testdata\Grid_sample_buffered.shp")
```

Comment: Add a screenshot/drawing showing what you want to do

Comment: I think what you need is complicated. It may not have a simple solution.

Comment: Should be able to use scale but the "buffer" will not be 1000 m everywhere

Comment: It looks to me like you want to resize the polygon, right?  Look at the picture in this question, is this what you need? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169694/is-there-arcpy-tool-for-polygon-resizing-like-scale-tool-of-advanced-editing-too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoPandas supports `cap_style` and `join_style` options in buffer. Since it is using shapely's buffer method, see their documentation on those options - https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.buffer.

```py
df2 = df.buffer(1000, cap_style=3, join_style=2)
```

However, although it can get closer to original shapes and angles than round buffer, keep in mind that in some cases it is simply not possible to buffer a geometry while preserving its shape.

Other option would be to scale geometry (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.affinity.scale). That preserves the original shape, but it may be tricky to get the correct dimension.